# What could be causing dampness in a bathroom wall?

Tags: bathroom, repair, water, walls

The bottom section of the wall (other side is bathroom and a closet) has the following appearance - after prying out the planks that decorate the floor/wall interface.

The wall (in a high rise) does not appear to be wet a foot above from the floor and looks like an internal leakage, any help would be much appreciated.

Thank you so so much!

[image]

Comment: Obviously water from somewhere--either a pipe or the sky. Leaks tend to appear where the water accumulates, which is apparently the bottom of the wall cavity in this case. Did you have a more specific question?

Comment: Wherever it's coming from, you're gonna wanna rip out the wet part of the wall so you can replace it. That might expose the source of the water.

Answer (score 1):

If it’s a wall in a high rise, I doubt if it’s a roof leak.

I’d guess 1) If there is a sink, toilet, etc. on the other side of the wall I’d check for  a loose pipe , or 2) I’d check for ventilation/condensation problem.

1) The leak might be from a loose drainline that only leaks when it’s really really full. That is to say, it could take years to produce enough water to create that mold. Fill up the sink/tub and see what happens.

2) If your exhaust fan duct is not insulated, it could create a lot of condensation which can accumulate and run to the floor. (However, I don’t see mold streaks, so I doubt it could be that...)

Comment: I have seen condensation problems without visible mold but agree +

Comment: Thank you so much for the responses. One particularity of the situation is that there is floorboard heating in the high rise - not sure if this detail matters. The other side of the wall is drainage/sink and was initially addressed but didn't seem to fix the issue.